# Convert Object into a primitive Property (Working Example)

Tags: javascript

My question is quite simple.
What is the most efficient way to convert the `person object` into a `personId (number)`

```js
let data = {
  person: {
    id: 1,
    name: "John"
  },
  randomProp: "Hello World"
};

console.log(data);
```

I basically just want to convert the above object so it looks like this:

```
data = {
   personId: 1,
   randomProp: "Hello World"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply configure a new object that contains the value of the `input` object.

On the below example, `data.person` represents the value of `person` key on data object.

```js
let data = {
  person: {
    id: 1,
    name: "John"
  },
  randomProp: "Hello World"
};

data = {
  personId: data.person.id,
  randomProp: data.randomProp
};
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = {
  person: {
    id: 1,
    name: "John"
  },
  randomProp: "Hello World"
};

data.personId = data.person.id;
delete data.person;

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object, pulling out the properties you want to retain, and passing them to a new object.

```js
const data = {
  person: {
    id: 1,
    name: "John"
  },
  randomProp: "Hello World"
};

const { person: { id: personId }, randomProp } = data;

const newData = { personId, randomProp };

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new map also. And after constructing your map object you can assign back to `data` object

```js
let data = {
  person: {
    id: 1,
    name: "John"
  },
  randomProp: "Hello World"
};
var map = {}; //Create a new map.
map.id = data.person.id; // Assign id
map.randomProp = data.randomProp; //Assign randomProp 
data = map;//Assign back map to data
console.log(data);
```